# Custom filter for html datalist

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" list="test">
  <datalist id="test">
            <option>apple orange grape</option>
            <option>apple blueberry grape</option>
            <option>blueberry strawberry raspberry</option>
        </datalist>
</body>

</html>
```

The normal behavior is that the list of options in the dropdown box only lists options that contain the string typed by the user.  So if the user types "apple" the first two options are displayed.

I want to use a custom filter, so if the user types multiple words it searches separately for each word - e.g. if they type "apple grape" the first two options should be displayed.  Currently no options would be listed, because none of the options contain the string "apple grape".

Is this possible?  I've found https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ which I think will do what I want and I think Bootstrap's autocomplete library will too but I was hoping I could do this with plain HTML/JS.

e: I think this is another way to describe what I'm trying to do:

```js
var a = ["apple orange grape", "apple blueberry grape", "blueberry strawberry raspberry"];

function filter(t) {
  var filterTerms = t.value.split(" ");
  var select = document.getElementById("select");
  select.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var match = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < filterTerms.length; j++) {
      if (a[i].indexOf(filterTerms[j]) == -1) {
        match = false;
      }
    }
    if (match) {
      select.appendChild(new Option(a[i], a[i]));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="filtertest" onkeyup="filter(this);">
<select id="select">
</select>
```

That JS makes it so the `select` only has options from the array `a` which match the filter in the text input. I want to combine the text input and `select` (like a text input with a `datalist`).

Comment: Datalist is basically an autocomplete feature, it doesn't have the capability you are looking for.

Comment: I don't have to use a datalist if there's another element that would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do does not make a lot of sense. If the user types "apple grape" what is the script supposed to do while typing? Should it start searching with "appl" already, or how is it supposed to know you finished typing and want to look for the string (without a "search now" button).

Based on jquery you could narrow a list while typing like that

```
$("document").ready(function () {

    $("#InputBox").on("keyup", function () {
        var searchText = $(this).val();
        searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
        searchText = searchText.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        $('#myList > li').each(function(){
            var currentLiText = $(this).text(),
                showCurrentLi = ((currentLiText.toLowerCase()).replace(/\s+/g, '')).indexOf(searchText) !== -1;

            $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

        });
    });
    inactivityTime();
});
```

Comment: After every character typed it should update the dropdown list - just like the default behavior, except the options that appear in the dropdown list are filtered differently.